# How can I compare two fields in diffrent two collections in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am beginner in the MongoDB.
Right now, I am making one query by using mongo. Please look this and let me know is it possible? If it is possible, how can I do?

```
collection:students 
[{id:a, name:a-name}, {id:b, name:b-name}, {id:c, name:c-name}]

collection:school
[{
    name:schoolA,
    students:[a,b,c]
}]

collection:room
[{ 
    name:roomA,
    students:[c,a]
}]
```

Expected result for roomA

```
 {
        name:roomA,
        students:[
            {id:a name:a-name isRoom:YES},
            {id:b name:b-name isRoom:NO},
            {id:c name:c-name isRoom:YES}
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: I am using latest version 3.4

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the `isRoom` property, but to perform a join across collections, you'd have two basic options:

- code it yourself, with multiple queries
- use the aggregation pipeline with `$lookup` operator

As a quick example of `$lookup`, you can take a given room, unwind its `students` array (meaning separate out each student element into its own entity), and then look up the corresponding student id in the `student` collection.

Assuming a slight tweak to your `room` collection document:

```
[{ 
    name:"roomA",
    students:[ {studentId: "c"}, {studentId: "a"}]
}]
```

Something like:

```
db.room.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind: "$students"
   },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "students",
            localField: "studentid",
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "classroomStudents"
        }
   },
   {
       $project:
           { _id: 0, name : 1 , classroomStudents : 1 }
    }
```

])

That would yield something like:

```
{ 
    name:"roomA",
    classroomStudents: [
        {id:"a", name:"a-name"},
        {id:"c", name:"c-name"}
    ]
}
```

*Disclaimer:* I haven't actually run this aggregation, so there may be a few slight issues. Just trying to give you an idea of how you'd go about solving this with `$lookup`.

More info on `$lookup` is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

Comment: Thanks, for your best answer. Then how will I integrate with school collection?

Comment: I have no idea how you want to integrate the school collection. But I showed you clearly how you can aggregate documents across collections, via the aggregation pipeline and `$lookup`. At this point, you should be able to figure out how to extend this example.